# mapserver expression: NOT in list

Tags: mapserver

In a mapfile I have a layer which has to be displayed differently, according to the values of an attribute. There are four different categories, A, B, C and all the rest.
A, B and C are no problem, but I don't manage to display all the rest. I tried to use a list-expression (EXPRESSION {A,B,C} see http://www.mapserver.org/de/mapfile/expressions.html#regular-expression-comparison), which I swap (NOT ...), but I can't get it to work...

```
CLASSITEM "zustaendigkeit"
CLASS
    EXPRESSION "AWN"
    NAME "AWN"
    STYLE
        COLOR  99 204 141
    END
END   
CLASS
    EXPRESSION "HBA"
    NAME "HBA"
    STYLE
        COLOR  246 179 166
    END
END
CLASS
    EXPRESSION "TBA"
    NAME "TBA"
    STYLE
        COLOR  175 182 224
    END
END
CLASS
# wrong too: EXPRESSION ("[zustaendigkeit]"!={TBA,HBA,AWN})       
EXPRESSION NOT {TBA,HBA,AWN}
    NAME "anderes"
    STYLE
        COLOR  224 206 232
    END
END
```

What's the right syntax? Thanks in advance.
Vera

Comment: which datasource are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not test now and maybe there is a better solution, but so should it work:

```
EXPRESSION ('[zustaendigkeit]'!= 'TBA' AND '[zustaendigkeit]' != 'HBA' AND '[zustaendigkeit]' != 'AWN')
```

Other solutions which could work:

```
EXPRESSION /^[TBA|HBA|AWN]/
EXPRESSION ("[zustaendigkeit]" NOT IN "TBA,HBA,AWN")
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found to use `NOT IN` statement is by adding another condition always true in `AND` with your condition.

```
EXPRESSION ('[field1]' = 'whatever_always_true' AND NOT '[zustaendigkeit]' IN ('TBA,HBA,AWN'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The first solution works fine, I get all areas except the ones of TBA, HBA and AWN. (My datasource is a POSTGIS-DB)

I tried the other two as well:

- EXPRESSION /^[TBA|HBA|AWN]/: I get the areas of TBA,HBA and AWN (with
  NOT it doesn't work)
- EXPRESSION ("[zustaendigkeit]" NOT IN    "TBA,HBA,AWN"): I don't get
  anything

Thanks.